# How to split django app in multiple folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I like to split my django app here in my case it's called `Core` in multiple folders like in the picture.
[image]
Example

```
Bank
---views
---urls
---models
---serializer

Currency
---views
---urls
---models
---serializer
```

I put in each folder the `__init.py__` file
here the **init** file from bank folder `

```
from .models import BimaCoreBank`
```

and here the `models.py` for bank folder

```
from core.abstract.models import AbstractModel
from core.country.models import BimaCoreCountry
from core.state.models import BimaCoreState


class BimaCoreBank(AbstractModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False, unique=True)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    street2 = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.ForeignKey(
        BimaCoreState, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    country = models.ForeignKey(
        BimaCoreCountry, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    bic = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
        permissions = []
        app_label = "BimaCoreBank"
```

and here the `urls.py` file from bank folder

from rest_framework import routers

from core.bank.views import BimaCoreBankViewSet

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()

app_name = 'BimaCoreBank'

urlpatterns = [
    router.register(r'bank', BimaCoreBankViewSet, basename='bank'),
]
```

It's the same on each folder,juste I changed the name of the class,

Now in the `__init.py__` file in core folder( the app folder that containt all the subfolders)

```
from . import bank
from . import country
from . import currency
from . import state
```

int the `urls.py` in the core folder I have this

```
from django.urls import path, include

app_name = 'core'

urlpatterns = [
    path('currency/', include('currency.urls.py')),
    path('country/', include('country.urls.py')),
    path('state/', include('state.urls.py')),
    path('bank/', include('bank.urls.py'))
]
```

and last in the app folder( the main folder of my project ) I have this in my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/schema/', SpectacularAPIView.as_view(), name='api-schema'),
    path(
        'api/docs/',
        SpectacularSwaggerView.as_view(url_name='api-schema'),
        name='api-docs',
    ),
    path('api/user/', include('user.urls')),
    path('api/core/', include('core.urls'))

]
```

It did not work,

first time  I add the `app_label` in `meta class` foreach folders(bank, currency ...)

then I added `'app_name'` in the `urls.py` file and it did not work too

Now the error message is this

```
(venv) rdm-bima@rdmbima-HP-EliteBook-850-G8-Notebook-PC:~/Downloads/bima_chiffre/app$ python3 manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/rdm-bima/Downloads/bima_chiffre/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rdm-bima/Downloads/bima_chiffre/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/rdm-bima/Downloads/bima_chiffre/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/home/rdm-bima/Downloads/bima_chiffre/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 398, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/home/rdm-bima/Downloads/bima_chiffre/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rdm-bima/Downloads/bima_chiffre/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/rdm-bima/Downloads/bima_chiffre/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/rdm-bima/Downloads/bima_chiffre/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 193, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/rdm-bima/Downloads/bima_chiffre/app/core/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import bank
  File "/home/rdm-bima/Downloads/bima_chiffre/app/core/bank/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .models import BimaCoreBank
  File "/home/rdm-bima/Downloads/bima_chiffre/app/core/bank/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from core.abstract.models import AbstractModel
  File "/home/rdm-bima/Downloads/bima_chiffre/app/core/abstract/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    from auditlog.registry import auditlog
  File "/home/rdm-bima/Downloads/bima_chiffre/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/auditlog/registry.py", line 325, in <module>
    auditlog = AuditlogModelRegistry()
  File "/home/rdm-bima/Downloads/bima_chiffre/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/auditlog/registry.py", line 52, in __init__
    from auditlog.receivers import log_access, log_create, log_delete, log_update
  File "/home/rdm-bima/Downloads/bima_chiffre/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/auditlog/receivers.py", line 6, in <module>
    from auditlog.context import threadlocal
  File "/home/rdm-bima/Downloads/bima_chiffre/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/auditlog/context.py", line 9, in <module>
    from auditlog.models import LogEntry
  File "/home/rdm-bima/Downloads/bima_chiffre/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/auditlog/models.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation
  File "/home/rdm-bima/Downloads/bima_chiffre/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/fields.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
  File "/home/rdm-bima/Downloads/bima_chiffre/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 137, in <module>
    class ContentType(models.Model):
  File "/home/rdm-bima/Downloads/bima_chiffre/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 127, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/rdm-bima/Downloads/bima_chiffre/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 260, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/rdm-bima/Downloads/bima_chiffre/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 138, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

My question is it possible to split a django app in multiple folder like I did? If not how to split a django app, because I don't like to have multiple model class in a same file

Thank you

for the `settings file`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'auditlog',
    'drf_spectacular',
    'core',
    'user',

]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can split up your django application however you want. This [write up](https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-best-practices-projects-vs-apps) talks about it.

You can check to see if there are any known errors detected by the [django command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/) in your application:

```
python manage.py check
```

or

```
django-admin check
```

If this error shows up,

> django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

Then without seeing your settings file; check if you have added the apps in INSTALLED_APPS, also check if you added a  SECRET_KEY.